# NFS : Requested transaction contains an unfixable cyclic ordering dependency: Transaction order is cyclic

Tags: systemd, nfs

I've been running NFS on this server and clients have been mounting successfully for years

Now today I have this error from client

```
showmount -e 10.0.0.110
clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered
```

Looking into this I see these suggestions

```
exportfs -ar
exportfs -a
```

systemctl restart nfs-server

It is on this last suggestion that I have this error

```
 systemctl status nfs-server
 ● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor pr>
    Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/nfs-server.service.d
             └─order-with-mounts.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)

Jun 23 15:09:04 acer systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Found ordering cycle on ex>
Jun 23 15:09:04 acer systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Found dependency on nfs-se>
Jun 23 15:09:04 acer systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Unable to break cycle star>
lines 1-9/9 (END)...skipping...
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/nfs-server.service.d
             └─order-with-mounts.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)

Jun 23 15:09:04 acer systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Found ordering cycle on export-3T.mount/start
Jun 23 15:09:04 acer systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Found dependency on nfs-server.service/start
Jun 23 15:09:04 acer systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Unable to break cycle starting with nfs-server.service/start
```

Looking into logs :

```
Jun 23 15:09:04 acer systemd[1]: Requested transaction contains an unfixable cyclic ordering dependency: Transaction order is cyclic. See system logs for det>
Jun 23 15:09:04 acer systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Unable to break cycle starting with nfs-server.service/start
Jun 23 15:09:04 acer systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Found dependency on nfs-server.service/start
Jun 23 15:09:04 acer systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Found ordering cycle on export-3T.mount/start
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Jun 23 15:09:04 acer systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Unable to break cycle starting with nfs-server.service/start
```

This means that you are stuck in an infinite cycle. You can visualize it with this command:

```
systemd-analyze dot nfs-server.service | dot -Tsvg > graph.svg
```

Use something like inkview to open the svg. Pay attention to green lines - they mean "After". You should see a loop somewhere: *a >>> b >>> c >>> a >>>* and so on or a simpler *a >>> b >>> a >>>*